# Get dump of fuse activemq messages

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-karaf, fuseesb

I am running a production application with fuse esb and using fuse provided activemq queues. There are 100k messages in one of my queues and I need to get a dump of those messages without removing them from the queue. What is the method to get a dump of those messages.

I used activemq:browse karaf command and directed output to file.But it did not give me all the messages. Only 4000 messages were written to a file.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ cannot browse extremely deep Queues so you won't likely be able to view them all.  The browse operation is limited to what can fit into the broker memory and by the maxBrowsePageSize setting.

There is no tooling to dump the contents of the message store offered in ActiveMQ.  A broker is not a database and should not be treated as one, messages are meant for consumers to consume.

Comment: I agree with Tim's assessment-- a broker is a tool for "data movement" not "data storage".